# How to load in Spark 2.1 XML file with repeating tags and attributes?

Tags: xml, parsing, apache-spark, xml-parsing, databricks

I have the xml file with such structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<new>
   <book id="bk101" language="en">
      <author id="4452" primary="true">Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title primary="true">XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre primary="false">Computer</genre>
      <publisher primary="true" id="US124">
        <firm id="4124">Amazon LLC</firm>
        <address>NY, USA</address>
        <email type="official">books@amazon.com</email>
        <contact_person id="3351">
            <name>Rajesh K.</name>
            <email type="personal">rajesh@amazon.com</email>
        </contact_person>
      </publisher>
    </book>
   <book id="bk103" language="en">
      <author id="4452" primary="true">Corets, Eva</author>
      <title primary="true">Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre primary="false">Fantasy</genre>
      <publisher primary="true" id="US136">
        <firm id="4524">Oreally LLC</firm>
        <address>NY, USA</address>
        <email type="official">books@oreally.com</email>
        <contact_person id="1573">
            <name>Prajakta G.</name>
            <email type="personal">prajakta@oreally.com</email>
        </contact_person>
      </publisher>
    </book>
   </new>
   <removed>
   <book id="bk104" language="en">
      <author id="4452" primary="true">Corets, Eva</author>
      <title primary="true">Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre primary="false">Fantasy</genre>
      <publisher primary="true" id="US137">
        <firm id="4524">Oreally LLC</firm>
        <address>NY, USA</address>
        <email type="official">books@oreally.com</email>
        <contact_person id="1573">
            <name>Prajakta G.</name>
            <email type="personal">prajakta@oreally.com</email>
        </contact_person>
      </publisher>
    </book>
   </removed>   
</catalog>
```

How could I load it in a DataSet?
I tried to follow the example [from Databricks](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/blob/master/README.md), but I received the error: `AnalysysException: Reference '_id' is ambiguous, could be: _id#1, _id#3`

> I've replaced in my StructType schema StructField '_id' to '_id#1',
>   '_id#2' and so on,

but I received another error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
                at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile(SparkContext.scala:1094)
                at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.XmlFile$.withCharset(XmlFile.scala:46)
                at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:62)
                at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource$$anonfun$createRelation$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:62)
                at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation.buildScan(XmlRelation.scala:54)
                at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation.buildScan(XmlRelation.scala:63)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$12.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:343)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$12.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:343)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:384)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$$anonfun$pruneFilterProject$1.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:383)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProjectRaw(DataSourceStrategy.scala:464)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.pruneFilterProject(DataSourceStrategy.scala:379)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSourceStrategy$.apply(DataSourceStrategy.scala:339)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$1.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:62)
                at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
                at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
                at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
                at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
                at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
                at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
                at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
                at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
                at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
                at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
                at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:79)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:75)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:84)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2791)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:636)
                at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:595)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found which solved the second error:

> add in `.pom` file old jackson version: jackson-core v.2.6.7 and
>   jackson-databind 2.6.7.